# Android checkbox state inspection

Tags: android, checkbox

I am inspecting the state of a checkbox. I am using the code below. When app starts (checkbox is unchecked), toast message says "unchecked". But when i open another screen and then go back, it doesn't say anymore. How to do that?
Partial code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
    if (cb1.isChecked())
    {
        Toast.makeText(main.this, "checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(main.this, "NOT checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

}

In this code i also have a

```
 cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
        {           
            //blablabla
        }
        });
```

part where i am inspecting the state of the checkbox when user clicks it.

I want to inspect the state of checkbox every time this screen shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()`.

[here](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/01/android-activity-lifecycle/) you can see the activity's lifecycle diagram, `onCreate()` is only called once, at the beginning of the activity's life...`onResume()` on the other hand is call each time the activity comes back to front.

However, the `OnCheckedChangeListener` stuff should be declared in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` as it will persist.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!
By the why the OnCheckedChangeListener stuff is  declared in onCreate() method.